# Centering 4 column list horizontally

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to center columns horizontally and have tried doing it via bootstrap columns but am having difficulties centering the columns that do not have a complete row. Id prefer to work with this using flexboxes but am open to other solutions as well.

**Trying to accomplish:**

[image]

I tried a few different approaches to this, one being ([jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hq5ak1d8/2/)). This is close, but was wondering if there is a way to start the new row from the center working it's way out?

Code I currently have:

**HTML**

```
<div class="list">
    <div class="col-3 mx-auto">
        <div class="card card-body mb-2">
            <h6>I'm .col-4</h6>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-3 mx-auto">
        <div class="card card-body mb-2">
            <h6>I'm .col-4</h6>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-3 mx-auto">
        <div class="card card-body mb-2">
            <h6>I'm .col-4</h6>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-3 mx-auto">
        <div class="card card-body mb-2">
            <h6>I'm .col-4</h6>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-3 mx-auto">
        <div class="card card-body mb-2">
            <h6>I'm .col-4</h6>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-3 mx-auto">
        <div class="card card-body mb-2">
            <h6>I'm .col-4</h6>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.landing-types .content-list .list {
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.landing-types .content-list .list .col-3 {
    -ms-flex: 0 0 25%;
    flex: 0 0 25%;
    max-width: 25%;
}
.landing-types .content-list .list .mx-auto {
    margin-left: auto !important;
    margin-right: auto !important;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is. Simply wrap the flexboxes and use `justify-content: center` (align center horizontally) and `align-items: center` (align center vertically).

Here is a minimal working example:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.column {
  width: 13%; /* Change this value to experiment */
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #000;
  color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<div class = "column">
  1
</div>
<div class = "column">
  2
</div>
<div class = "column">
  3
</div>
<div class = "column">
  4
</div>
<div class = "column">
  5
</div>
<div class = "column">
  6
</div>
<div class = "column">
  7
</div>
<div class = "column">
  8
</div>
<div class = "column">
  9
</div>
<div class = "column">
  10
</div>
<div class = "column">
  11
</div>
<div class = "column">
  12
</div>
```

If you haven't, you **need** to read this guide about flexbox: [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

*This is not related to flexbox, but I recommend you read about grids: [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/)*

Answer (score 0):

this is it:

html:

```
<div class="flex-container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>  
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>  
  <div>7</div>
  <div>8</div>
  <div>9</div>  
  <div>10</div> 
</div>
```

css:

```
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction:row;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
   max-width:350px;
   justify-content:center;



}

.flex-container > div {
  background-color: #194f27;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

check:https://jsfiddle.net/yfvp5m69/24/